# Change Background Color of Libreoffice Writer Comments

Tags: xubuntu, themes, libreoffice, colors

I am using Xubuntu 14.04. I have the Libreoffice PPA added for the latest version of LibreOffice writer. (I have the latest version installed to be able to print to PDF with comments on the side.)

I see there are a couple of posts on this already. However, they are all at least a couple of years old.  I've looked into it, and I do not see where they've added this feature to change the background color of comments. So, I am assuming it is not a configuration option.  However, I am curious if I can access the LibreOffice writer program files in some location to change this color. For example, in the past in OS X, I was able to change the background color of the native Notes app from yellow to very light gray. In this case, I only needed to change the color of a png file. Or, I am curious if there is a hexadecimal or RGB number in a file that could be changed. Much thanks in advance. Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have LibreOffice version 4.4.2.2 in Xubuntu 14.04. I noticed that I can change the background color of the comments to my liking if I go to Tools > Options > LibreOffice > User Data. There I would add myself as an owner with a certain name (for example, my first and last name, only my first name, etc.). Then I would close and add a comment. Each time there was a new name, there was a new background color for the comment. I did this until I came across a color I liked. Then I stuck with that name. I think the different colors may be coming from the Xfce theme colors I have installed, although I am not 100% sure. It is pretty nice to just stumble upon an answer. :)